# Little Bic for France

Tags: civisepa

Does the Little BIC extension work for France and how does it work?

I read the short [documentation](https://github.com/Project60/org.project60.bic) but couldn't figure out if I had to download BIC codes for France or not. And if so, how it should look like.

Any informations about it?

best regards,
Guillaume

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a UI function to get/update BICs for several countries under yourdomain.org/civicrm/bicImport?reset=1

Afaik there is no source for French BICs yet. In order to add French BIC you would need to:

1. find a freely available list/source of French BIC
2. implement fetching/parsing the list in LittleBIC

If you cannot do 2. you may create an [issue in Github](https://github.com/Project60/org.project60.bic/issues) once you found the list - maybe someone can implememt it for you.

Comment: I found this comprehensive list on git : https://github.com/franckverrot/codes-bic-france/blob/master/codes-bic-france.csv

Comment: Thanks Fabian. I've created an issue on Github. I hope someone could handle this enhancement.